# Como criar um background transparente ou incolor em css?

Tags: java, css, admob, background-color

Qual o codigo em css para deixar o background transparente, ou incolor? Estou criando um anuncio Nativo no Admob e preciso que o fundo fique transparente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consegui criar a transparencia que eu precisava, usei o codigo abaixo no CSS :

`body {
  background-color:rgba(144,  203,  44,  0.4);
}`

deixando o alfa com um numero menor ele retia a opacidade, se deixar em "0", ele fica totalmente transparente ! no meu caso deixei com 0.4

Comment: Tentou somente `background-color: transparent;`?

Comment: Tentei sim, mas nao deu certo !